# question about a bison documentation example of resolving shift/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, shift-reduce-conflict

When I read the bison document, I found a example:

```
%token ID
%%
s: a ID
a: expr
expr: %empty | expr ID ’,’
```

and the document tells us it has a shift/reduce conflict:

```
First example: expr • ID ’,’ ID $end
Shift derivation
$accept
→ 0: s                             $end
    → 1: a                     ID
        → 2: expr
            → 4: expr • ID ’,’
Second example: expr • ID $end
Reduce derivation
$accept
→ 0: s                     $end
    → 1: a             ID
        → 2: expr •
```

we can found this conflict is due to when stack is `expr ID ’,’` and the next symbol is `ID`, it can reduce to `expr` (because `s: a ID`), or shift ID.

then it gives a solution:

```
expr: ID | ’,’ expr ID
```

> Attach the original document sentence: 
> This conflict is caused by the parser not having enough information to know the difference
> between these two examples. The parser would need an additional lookahead token to know
> whether or not a comma follows the ID after expr. These types of conflicts tend to be more
> difficult to fix, and usually need a rework of the grammar. In this case, it can be fixed by
> changing around the recursion: expr: ID | ’,’ expr ID.

BUT why `ID | ’,’ expr ID` ? This directly modifies the terminal that can be matched on!
Just eg. `ID , ID , ID` it cannot work!

I wonder why the documentation says, find a grammar that resolves the conflict without changing the match.

ps. this is the document [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.pdf) and it's ver. is `10 September 2021, Bison Version 3.8.1`, p146-147

Comment: ps. I have tried to eliminate the left recursion, but actually conflict still exists.